# Написание и сохранение текста

Tags: php, html, css

Предположим, что есть одностраничный сайт с полем для ввода, кнопкой "Отправить" и текстом снизу.

Каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы любой пользователь после ввода текста и нажатия кнопки "Отправить" мог добавить новый текст к предыдущему с последующим сохранением этого текста на сайте?

Comment: Или предварительная регистрация с логином/паролем. Или при первом добавлении сообщения пользователю в браузер записывается кука со случайным неповторимым длинным идентификатором, который в дальнейшем и используется для доступа к сообщениям с таким же идентификатором автора.

Comment: http://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html#grovelling